# Silverlight Bubble Chart Fixed Size Item

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I am currently using the silverlight toolkit bubble series.

I created a control template that uses ellipse.

```
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>

                <ContentControl>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Shortname}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Importance, stringFormat='Importance: {0}%'}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Urgency, StringFormat='Urgency: {0}%'}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContentControl>
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverHighlight"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionHighlight"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="RevealStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Shown">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Ellipse Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" MouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown">

            </Ellipse>

        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I have a property Size which I assigned to the SizeValuePath of the Bubble Series.

If the value of Size is 10, I am expecting the height and width of my ellipse is also 10

Somehow the Bubble Series is scaling, would it be possible to have fix size for my ellipse?

Comment: What do you mean by the value of size? What value? Also how is it scaling, sorry a bit difficult to visualize your issue.

Comment: I want the width and height of my ellipse to be 10. The data that i am binding have a property called Size.

Comment: Why not add MaxHeight="10" and MaxWidth="10" to Ellipse?

Comment: Ya like @Musters said if 10 is the static size you want, just set your Height/Width on your ellipse to 10

Comment: Thanks, binding size to MaxHeight and MaxWidth works